# How to catch network errors with Axios request interceptor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Our Vue application had some problems and I noticed in Sentry logs that probably the network has been unreliable:

```
Error: Network Error
Error: Request aborted
```

I would like to show warning to the user, but couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to catch these errors using Axios request interceptor, but they didn't work. Has anyone accomplished this?

EDIT:

This is the interceptor that didn't work. I also have a response interceptor to catch 403 and it works perfectly.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(undefined, (err) => {
  // Never gets here for network errors
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: @EstusFlask I edited the question with a sample code.

Comment: Why is it request interceptor? You need to handle a response. If you handle Axios errors consistently, you won't get unhandled errors. Network error is detected like `!error.status && error.message === 'Network Error'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
return Promise.reject(error);
```

like this:

```html
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: What's the purpose of rethrowing an error when there's an error? It's a noop.

Comment: Thanks!! I thought a request that was not sent would be seen in request interceptor.

The Axios docs could be a bit more precise.